# discord.js { split: true } will not split

Tags: discord.js

I try to split more than 2000 chars from a file, but the
`{ split: true }`
seem not to work, any here know what I'm doing wrong.. here my full code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');
const date = require('date-and-time');
const readLastLines = require('read-last-lines');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const now = new Date();

var settings = require("./settings.js");
var channel = require("./settings.js");
var playlist = "text.txt"

bot.on("ready", function () {
    console.log("ready");
//  console.log("Stream ready - Starting live Playlist...." + date.format(now, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
//      bot.channels.cache.get(settings.discord_channel).send("Stream ready - Starting live Playlist...." + date.format(now, 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
});


fs.watchFile(playlist, (eventType, filename) => {
readLastLines.read(playlist, 255)
        .then((lines) => bot.channels.cache.get(settings.discord_channel).send(lines, { split: true }));
});

bot.login(settings.bot_token);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` option for [MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) was removed in v13. You now have to import the Util class and use it's [splitMessage()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage) method.

You'll need to split the message into chunks and then asynchronously loop through each chunk, awaiting the sending of each.

```js
const { Util } = require('discord.js');

// Your code 

readLastLines.read(playlist, 255)
   .then(async lines => {
      const channel = bot.channels.cache.get(settings.discord_channel);

      // Splitting and sending
      const messageChunks = Util.splitMessage(lines, {
         maxLength: 2000,
         char: ' '
      });

      messageChunks.forEach(async chunk => {
         await channel.send(chunk);
      });
   });
```